# Naudio record microphone for X amount of seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, naudio

Currently I can record the microphone input using the Naudio .dll with this:

```
public void recordInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Now recording...");
    waveSource = new WaveIn();
    waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 1);

    waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
    waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);
    //string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".wav");

    string tempFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Nick\Desktop",  "test.wav");


    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);

    waveSource.StartRecording();

    myTimer.Interval = 5000;
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Start();

}
```

Currently I used an eventhandler to wait for 5 seconds and then onTick I stop recording. However this is causing problems because I am having trouble waiting for the recording task to finish in the main part of the code where I call:

```
    public string voiceToText()
    {
        recordInput();

        //Somehow wait here until record is done then proceed.

        convertToFlac();
        return "done";


    }
```

I've tried putting the Naudio in a thread and using a `waitOne();` but `waveSource.StartRecording();` is put in an eventhandler and thread an expection. I've also tried using a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` and stop recording after that thread finishes but the audio only records the first 500mS of audio for some reason.

I'm pretty new to c# and don't fully understand threading so any help or seperate approach is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't running in a Windows Forms or WPF application, then you should use `WaveInEvent` instead, so that a background thread is set up to handle the callbacks. The default constructor for `WaveIn` uses Windows messages.

Comment: A thats good to know. I can put it in a thread now without an exception. Any suggestions on the best way of just recording for a 5 second interval?

Comment: well you can know how much you've recorded by tracking how many bytes you receive in the DataAvailable event (and using WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic, but here is some code that I made for one of my projects and that records audio for x seconds (it uses NAudio.Lame to convert the wave file to mp3):

```
public class Recorder
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Timer used to start/stop recording
    /// </summary>
    private Timer _timer;

    private WaveInEvent _waveSource;
    private WaveFileWriter _waveWriter;
    private string _filename;
    private string _tempFilename;
    public event EventHandler RecordingFinished;

    /// <summary>
    /// Record from the mic
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seconds">Duration in seconds</param>
    /// <param name="filename">Output file name</param>
    public void RecordAudio(int seconds, string filename)
    {
        /*if the filename is empty, throw an exception*/
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The file name cannot be empty.");

        /*if the recording duration is not > 0, throw an exception*/
        if (seconds <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The recording duration must be a positive integer.");

        _filename = filename;
        _tempFilename = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)}.wav";

        _waveSource = new WaveInEvent
        {
            WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1)
        };

        _waveSource.DataAvailable += DataAvailable;
        _waveSource.RecordingStopped += RecordingStopped;
        _waveWriter = new WaveFileWriter(_tempFilename, _waveSource.WaveFormat);

        /*Start the timer that will mark the recording end*/
        /*We multiply by 1000 because the Timer object works with milliseconds*/
        _timer = new Timer(seconds * 1000);

        /*if the timer elapses don't reset it, stop it instead*/
        _timer.AutoReset = false;

        /*Callback that will be executed once the recording duration has elapsed*/
        _timer.Elapsed += StopRecording;

        /*Start recording the audio*/
        _waveSource.StartRecording();

        /*Start the timer*/
        _timer.Start();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback that will be executed once the recording duration has elapsed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void StopRecording(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*Stop the timer*/
        _timer?.Stop();

        /*Destroy/Dispose of the timer to free memory*/
        _timer?.Dispose();

        /*Stop the audio recording*/
        _waveSource.StopRecording();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback executed when the recording is stopped
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        _waveSource.DataAvailable -= DataAvailable;
        _waveSource.RecordingStopped -= RecordingStopped;
        _waveSource?.Dispose();
        _waveWriter?.Dispose();

        /*Convert the recorded file to MP3*/
        ConvertWaveToMp3(_tempFilename, _filename);

        /*Send notification that the recording is complete*/
        RecordingFinished?.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback executed when new data is available
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_waveWriter != null)
        {
            _waveWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            _waveWriter.Flush();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the recorded WAV file to MP3
    /// </summary>
    private void ConvertWaveToMp3(string source, string destination)
    {
        using (var waveStream = new WaveFileReader(source))
        using(var fileWriter = new LameMP3FileWriter(destination, waveStream.WaveFormat, 128))
        {
            waveStream.CopyTo(fileWriter);
            waveStream.Flush();
        }

        /*Delete the temporary WAV file*/
        File.Delete(source);
    }

}
```

And here is how to use it in your code:

```
        var rec = new Recorder();
        /*This line allows us to be notified when the recording is complete and the callback 'OnRecordingFinished' will be executed*/
        rec.RecordingFinished += OnRecordingFinished;
        rec.RecordAudio(seconds, recPath);

    private void OnRecordingFinished(object sender, RecordingContentArgs e)
    {
        //Put your code here to process the audio file


    }
```