# Access Violation calling WaveInEvent.StopRecording()

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, access-violation, naudio

I'm trying to use [Zak's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858983/7186007) to periodically acquire few seconds from microphone and to write each recording to a different file. I put it in a Windows.Form C# application in VS2017 with .NET framework 4.7.2. I used the current Nuget package NAudio 2.0.0
After some apparently working time, possibly after some hours, the application crashes with Access Violation Exception. Note that even a try/catch block could not trap the exception and this is catched by the Windows Events Register:

```
Applicazione: TestAudioAcquisitionForms.exe
Versione framework: v4.0.30319
Descrizione: il processo è stato terminato a causa di un'eccezione non gestita.
Informazioni sull'eccezione: System.AccessViolationException
in NAudio.Wave.WaveInterop.waveInReset(IntPtr)
in NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent.StopRecording()
in Recorder_ns.NAudio.Recorder.TimerElapsed(System.Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
in System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object)
in System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
in System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
in System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
in System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
in System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Edit: tested with .NET framework 4.7.2 (was 4.5.2 with NAudio 1.10.0) the exception is still present

Comment: Are you sure your NAudio WaveIn object is not garbage collected?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I had that suspect, first of all I keep the reference in my main Form object for all the recording time. Secondarily i tried forcing manual asyncronous garbage collections (with a System.Timers.Timer) with GC.Collect() but the problem doesn't seem to worsen. So I tend to exclude it...

Comment: Have you found an answer to your problem. I'm having the same problem.